# Cygwin: Scala interpreter quits abruptly when run in background

Tags: bash, scala, shell, cygwin

Consider the following shell function:

```
run_in_background() {
  type scala
  java -version
  /cygdrive/c/Development/Software/scala-2.12.0/bin/scala -version
    scala -version
}
```

Command: `run_in_background`

Output:

```
Kshitiz.Sharma /cygdrive/c/Development/temp
$ run_in_background
scala is hashed (/cygdrive/c/Development/Software/scala-2.12.0/bin/scala)
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
Scala code runner version 2.12.0 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
Scala code runner version 2.12.0 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Command: `run_in_background &`

Output:

```
Kshitiz.Sharma /cygdrive/c/Development/temp
$ run_in_background  &
[7] 12712
scala is hashed (/cygdrive/c/Development/Software/scala-2.12.0/bin/scala)

Kshitiz.Sharma /cygdrive/c/Development/temp
$ java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)


[7]+  Stopped                 run_in_background
```

I'm really at a loss as to why this is happening. Why should scala interpreter care if its running in the background? Why does it abruptly quit?

I'm using bash on Cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for paths is inconsistent, i.e. some paths are not correctly interpreted under Cygwin, and it's a bit of a hit-and-miss. Try `cygpath` to make your paths Windows-compatible.
Also: I have a good experience with Babun, a Cygwin distribution. Like you, I develop Scala on Windows. You may want to try it out.

```
if [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 6)" == "CYGWIN" ];then
    echo "Detected CYGWIN environment"
    #If running in cygwin then ensure paths are windows compatible
    SBT_LAUNCHER="`cygpath -w $SBT_LAUNCHER`"
fi
```

Comment: Babun looks interesting. Would try it out. I hope it doesn't break scripts written under Cygwin. Does it have cygpath etc?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's lightweight, self-updating... feels more modern. All I need is a shell environment to run Scala/Java, and it does that. I have not tried all the features that come with classic Cygwin because I do not need them

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @radumanolescu for pointing me in the right direction.

Scala comes with two set of scripts, one for Linux and other for Windows. When you type `scala` in a Cygwin window it will execute the Linux script.

Cygwin does not have 100% compatibility and does not always succeed in running these scripts, this being one of those cases.

The fix was to use the windows batch file instead of linux shell script. Added this to the bash profile:

```
scala() {
    scala.bat "$@"
}; export -f scala
```

`export -f` to export the function so that it is available to any subshells.